# Java AWT Frame is unaffected by night light

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, frame

I was building for the first time an actual application in Java using `java.awt.Frame`. But then I switched instead to `javax.swing.JFrame`, which I heard is more recent and generelly better (right?), and I noticed that the app, which used to be completely white, is now a little bit more yellow-ish (because I use Windows Night light and my screen is set to "Warm"). This is not a problem, I was just wondering why Frame doesn't care but JFrame does.

Comment: Take a look at [How to use Root Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) - `JFrame` is a "composite" component - that is, it contains a series of components which are layered on top of it in order to provide it's over all functionality, this is the reason for the difference